# PHP format date dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy based on locale

Tags: php

I'm searching for a way to switch a date format which is 2017-11-11 to a format which is:

dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy based on locale.

I'm already using IntlDateFormatter but the issue is here that when I want to have a year like: 2017 I need to use IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM which will output:

```
Jan 12, 1952
```

The IntlDateFormatter::SHORT will output:

```
12/13/52
```

There seems no way between it based on locale and I would like to have some way to accomplish this in PHP and not in the frontend.

What are my chances here using something instead of:

```
date_format($date,"Y/m/d");
```

Comment: Can't you use the IntlDateFormatter's [setPattern()](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.setpattern.php) method to specify the formatting that you want?

Comment: Stop using `date_format` and use one of the `dateTime` objects as illustrated in [**zstate's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47242093/3536236). Welcome to 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use it like that:

```
$dateFormatter = IntlDateFormatter::create(
    "en_US", //locale
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, //datetype
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, //timetype
    'America/Los_Angeles', //timezone
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, //calendar
    "MM/dd/yyyy" //pattern
);

echo $dateFormatter->format(new DateTime('2017-01-12'));
```

Without specifying the pattern it will use `IntlDateFormatter::FULL`.

Timezone, calendar and pattern are optional. Look at the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php).
The default value for calendar is `NULL`, which corresponds to `IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN`.

Comment: Yes I found something like this but I still need to set, locale, format and timezone, what about the GREGORIAN ? It confuses me as I thought it was "baked" in PHP for some way.

Comment: @Fabb see my updated answer, the calendar is optional.

Comment: thanks, but still, why do you need to set the pattern, is there no way to determ the pattern automaticly ? I don't know them out of my head for every locale. I would expect it would be referenced somewhere.

Comment: The pattern is determined automatically via the defaults for datetype and timetype, if you're happy to accept those defaults, but you wanted a custom pattern

Comment: You are right but a default pattern with Y, so 2017, would be logic as well